# Create an instance of Exception and modify its message

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin/Java, I would like to inherit from Exception but change the message when the Exception is instantiated. Something like this:

```
import java.lang.Exception

class TestAlreadyAddedException : Exception {
    constructor(details: String) {
       this.message = "Test already added: {details}" 
    }
}
```

But this is not allowed because Kotlin complains that message is a val that cannot be re-assigned. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception class takes it's message as a constructor parameter.

This should do it:

```
constructor(details: String): super(details) { 

}
```

Comment: It should be `constructor(details: String): super(details) { }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

**Create simple exception class**

```
class TestException(message:String): Exception(message)
```

**Use it like this**

```
throw TestException("Test already added: $message")
```

Comment: To match the question, I think it should be more like `class TestAlreadyAddedException(message: String): Exception("Test already added: $message")`.